# How can I get older versions of the Eclipse IDE to run on MacOS Monterey?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I recently upgraded my laptop from MacOS Catalina to MacOS Monterey, and all my existing Eclipse IDE installs stopped working. The UI doesn't work, and I will frequently get this popup and lots of error events in the error log (see below):

[image: Problem Occurred popup]

I have installs of Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) and Eclipse Oxygen 3.A (4.7.3a) that are both showing the same problem.  It seems the core problem is here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:138)
```

Is there any way to fix them? I have to use older versions because of dependencies on old unmaintained Eclipse plugins.

If there's no way to fix it, what's the precise issue? I'm curious, and I haven't been able to find anything about it.

## Information

Mac OS 12.7.1 (21G920) (on Intel x64).

Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) Build id: 20180917-1800

Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) Build id: M20180330-0640

JDK: Amazon Corretto 1.8.0_332

## Error Log Details (Eclipse 2018-09)

Error log snippet:
[image: Error log snippet]

1st Error Event:

[image: 1st Event Details]

1st Error Event Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(CLabel.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.computeSize(CLabel.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLine$StatusLineLayout.computeSize(StatusLine.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Composite.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout.computeSize(TrimBarLayout.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout.access$0(TrimBarLayout.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout$TrimLine.addControl(TrimBarLayout.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout.computeSize(TrimBarLayout.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Composite.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimmedPartLayout.layout(TrimmedPartLayout.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1267)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setLayoutDeferred(Composite.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredLayouts(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3719)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

2nd Error Event Details:

[image: 2nd error event example]

2nd Error Event Details Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.getWidthHint(StatusLineContributionItem.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateActionBars(WorkbenchWindow.java:2406)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActionBars(WorkbenchPage.java:4498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActionSwitcher.updateTopEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActiveEditorSources(WorkbenchPage.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$4(WorkbenchPage.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$7.run(PartServiceImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartBroughtToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.access$4(PartServiceImpl.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4905)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.lambda$3(StackRenderer.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3198)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1881)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.lambda$0(CTabFolder.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1512)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1324)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4116)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3733)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

Comment: A ton of patches would be needed for that, especial [macOS 11 alias Big Sur needed a lot of adaption](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/showdependencytree.cgi?id=565691&hide_resolved=0). What do you mean by _"I have to use older versions because of dependencies on old unmaintained Eclipse plugins"_? In most cases, old plugins works also in current Eclipse versions.

Comment: Only the most recent versions of Eclipse work well on macOS 11 onward. The Eclipse regularly needs updates to deal with changes Apple make to their GUI APIs.